# Including modules in Netlify AWS lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, netlify

I’ve looked at the tutorials but I don’t understand. I have a function that processes stripe payments. I think it has something to do with packages.json but I can’t find information about where to put it or how to run it.

This is the code:

```
https://github.com/alexmacarthur/netlify-lambda-function-example/blob/master/lambda-src/purchase.js
```

With the important line simply being:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

The error I get is:

```
{"errorMessage":"Cannot find module 'dotenv'"
```

How do I set about including this? Do I have to put a packages.json file in the same folder as my function? I tried that and it didn’t make any difference.

Comment: Did you include your `node_modules` into your deployment package? According to [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html), you must do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install  `npm i dotenv --save`